# How to slice from 4d matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Let us say I've got a 4-d matrix `A` of shape `[2,4,5,5]` in numpy. I want to play with the second dimension i.e 4. I have a 2d array `idx=[[1,2],[0,3]]`.

I want output to be something like this:

`B= A[:,idx,:,:]` i.e. `B` must be of shape `[2,2,5,5]`.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this efficiently?

Comment: Explain how a (2,2) index is supposed to produce just 2 'rows'.  Or illustrate with a (2,4) array.  `A[:,idx,:,:]` will be (2,2,2,5,5) where the inner (2,2) reflects the shape of `idx`.  What else can it be?

Comment: Yeah that's the problem. I am getting the output to be 5-d but want the output to have shape (2,2,5,5).

Comment: I can explain to you in terms of images. Dim-0 is batch_size, dim-1 is #channels, dim-2 is height and dim-3 is width. I want to keep only a few channels form each image in the batch. For example base on the question, each image has 4 channels and I want to keep only channel  1 and 2 for the first image and channel 0 and 3 for the second image in the batch.

Comment: Try `A[J, idx]` where `J=[[0], [1]]`, a (2,1) array that broadcasts with (2,2).  You are indexing on 2 dimensions, not just 1.

Comment: @hpaulj Thaks for the answer. It's working.